# Relationship normal matrix and block diagonal matrix

Tags: matrices

Can it be claimed that every block diagonal matrix is ​​a normal matrix?
$A \text{ normal} \quad \iff \quad A^*A = AA^*$

Comment: What do you mean by normal matrix? Can every matrix be considered as a block matrix with a single block of n*n?

Comment: @Shaq $A \text{ normal} \quad \iff \quad A^*A = AA^*$

Comment: Ohh right, had in mind normal distribution and was like, hey, whats normal matrix is in that context. Well I guess the answer is no, since every $A$ which is not normal, can be expressed as a block matrix with a single block, don't you agree?

Comment: @Shaq I almost agree, but I can not find a counterexample

Comment: Try [[1, i],[0,1]] where - [1, i] is first row, [0,1] second row

Comment: @Shaq Thank you

Comment: note that if true: every block diagonal matrix is a normal matrix$\implies$ every matrix is a normal matrix